# Evaluate meaning in Math

Tags: meaning

In Hebrew I don't know the translation of evaluate:
What is correct (and why?):
(1) evaluate equation
(2) evaluate expression
(3) evaluate formula

Can you give more example when we use the verb evaluate in math?

Comment: I removed the explicit translation request because we don’t do translations. Your question may still be closed as “lacking details”, “answerable with a dictionary”, or something else. You should [edit] your question to include your own research and understanding. See [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) for examples.

Comment: Assuming that a dictionary definition isn't helping with the meaning of *evaluate*, I don't understand the distinction you're trying to make between the three sentences. You can use any number of nouns after *evaluate*. The three used in your sentences are only a small number of possibilities. If you're actually asking for a list of nouns, that's beyond the scope of this site. (Also note that you haven't given actual sentences—and all three phrases are missing some grammatical elements. *Evaluate* ***(an / the / this / that)*** *expression*, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would say *solve an equation*, but when it comes to expressions, that's them that you evaluate. It's common to see it phrased like this in math books: *evaluate the following expression*. Formulas are just that—formulas. You neither solve them nor evaluate them. You simply use them. There is just nothing about them that could be evaluated or solved. But, you certainly could use them to help you solve an equation or evaluate an expression. So, I would opt for #2 as the correct answer.